# Two aside in one button

Tags: javascript, css, html, angularjs

Hi I have this ASIDE showing when a BUTTON/LINK was click.
As you can see the "Go to the next Aside" in ASIDE code is a button.

What I want to happen is when clicking the "Go to the next Aside" button, a new aside page will show in replace to the ASIDE page/code below with transition effect. The next aside should also a have "back" option.
I want to know the corresponding HTML code for this.

I was about to search but I can't explain my problem.

### BUTTON/LINK

```
<!-- Button/Link -->
<a class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#container">
    <span class="icon-bars" title="Options"></span>
</a>
```

### ASIDE

```
<!-- Aside -->
<aside>
    <div id="container" class="modal fade fade-right" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">Options</div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm ichris-default-button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Go to the next Aside"></span>
                            Go to the next Aside
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want a jQuery Carousel Plugin that can be customized to fit your requirements
take a look at this demo [here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?Fydaph_O)
and more examples [here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-carousel-example/)